# What would cause a long delay between turning on faucet and water coming out?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure

There has been an increasingly long delay from the time the water faucet is turned on to when the water comes out. This usually happens first thing in the morning when turning on the cold water at the sink.  Sometimes it happens during the day after no one has used any water for a few hours.

It used to be a few seconds but now the delay can be anywhere from 15 seconds to more than a minute. Just before the water comes out, there is an audible clunking sound that sounds like it comes from under the house but we're not sure.

This happens at the bathroom and kitchen sinks -- wherever the water gets turned on first. It doesn't happen every morning, but it happens pretty regularly.

We live in a warm climate year-round so cold weather is not a factor.

What might cause this delay and how do I troubleshoot and fix it?

Comment: This is a delay between opening the valve and actually getting water, not a delay in waiting for hot water, right? Also, just to be clear, it only happens on the cold water, or does it happen if you turn on the hot water first?

Comment: Are you on a city water system?  There should be only 6 inches to a maybe a foot from the tap to faucet, so almost instant water.  If no leaks in your house/water meter readings are normal, I would suspect a leak in the city lines, sucking your water out, more distance for the water to travel to the faucet.

Comment: is there a noise before the water comes out, like rushing air? Can you feel airflow? Kitchen sinks are usually (in countries I know) fed directly from the incoming supply, while bathroom sinks may not be in some houses, so the kitchen is the best test.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is on a well pump, and it's taking that long for the pressure switch to notice that a tap has been opened...

Comment: I'm guessing you are on well water and your pump has a bad pressure tank and a bad pressure switch too.